# Selenium WD: different pages appear while open them manually and if using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have faced with the next problem: when I would like to open manually login page of my application (let it be e.g. `**hello**.example.com/login`) I can see one page style and DOM structure.
But when I am trying to start application using Selenium WebDriver (and therefore `Chrome is controlled by automated test software`), suddenly I can see another page that I have on this domain (e.g. `**hi**.example.com/login`) and this domain's DOM structure. URL in the browser as I have expected (first link), but the appearance and DOM as if I am on another page (second link).

Tried to use incognito window without any plugins and settings, but it didn't help.

Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94 (64-bit);
Chromedriver version 2.33.506120;
Win 10.

What problem it could be?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sharing your WebDriver between tests / methods?

Comment: @marcel No, I have static driver instance and launch only one test class in order to find a problem.

Comment: @NikitaLohich Share your code trials & relevant `HTML`

Comment: Incognito mode will not help as `WebDriver` opens the browser in a clean session. Without cookies or cache. We don't have enough information to help you.

Provide an example from your browser and when Chrome is running

Comment: @RafałLaskowski [manually opened](https://imgur.com/Br8G8xN) and [opened by Selenium WD](https://imgur.com/5up66ST). See the screenshots attached please.

Comment: @DebanjanB you can also look at my links above, thanks

Comment: Can you help us with a formatted & textual `HTML` for further analysis?

Comment: @nikitalohich Looks like your browser has some security setting which blocks the page from rendering correctly. 
Automated chrome does look good and renders elements as they should.

Make sure you have Javascript turned on, add a security exception in your browser.

Comment: @RafałLaskowski your thoughts were in the right direction - the issue was because of some different exceptions appear while rendering page. I looked at console and find them. When using automated chrome - there is no such exceptions at all. I'll try to find out what is going on. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help :)